# Extracting HTML tag properties and values

Tags: html, xml

Is it possible to extract the properties and values in a HTML file and export them to a XML file?

Comment: Can you give sample input and expected output?

Comment: Yes. If you want more info, describe what you are trying to achieve and what language(s) you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.
A HTML File IS a (more or less) a XML file.
You can use XSLT (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) for transforming HTML/XML to another HTML/XML.
Or you can use any other language like PHP with xmldom.